# Assign if variable is set

Tags: php, variables

In PHP I find myself writing code like this frequently:

```
$a = isset($the->very->long->variable[$index])
            ? $the->very->long->variable[$index]
            : null;
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Preferably one that doesn't require me to write `$the->very->long->variable[$index]` twice.

Comment: By working OOP and use the __get and __set?

Comment: @DaHaKa: That might issue a warning on a server with good settings (`E_STRICT | E_ALL)`

Comment: You could use a reference if you're using the same long variable often: `$ref = $the->very->long->variable; $a = !empty($ref[$index]) ? $ref[$index] : null; $b = !empty($ref[++$index])...`, or as @Bondye pointed out, use the magic getter method, and set it to return _either_ null or the property value

Comment: Looks like that `->variable` could implement/wrapped into [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) and give back NULL per default for an unset index in an [`offsetGet`](http://php.net/arrayaccess.offsetget) operation. - Also please double-check for potential duplicates, you could find some gems on this site.

Comment: The maybe monad might work for this, although I don't understand it well enough to say for certain: https://github.com/ircmaxell/monad-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly no, because the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor) has been declined. And because [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is not a function but a language construct you cannot write your own function for this case.

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions.

Answer (score 59):

An update, because PHP 7 is now out and is a game-changer on this point ; the previous answers are about PHP 5.

PHP 7 solves this issue. Because you are true at saying that it is frequent to write this in PHP, and that's absolutely not elegant.

In PHP 7 comes the [Null Coalesce Operator (RFC)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), which is a perfect shorthand for the isset ternary condition.

Its goal is to replace this type of condition:

```
$var = isset($dict['optional']) ? $dict['optional'] : 'fallback';
```

By that:

```
$var = $dict['optional'] ?? 'fallback';
```

Even better, the null coalesce operators are chainable:

```
$x = null;
# $y = null; (undefined)
$z = 'fallback';

# PHP 7
echo $x ?? $y ?? $z   #=> "fallback"

# PHP 5
echo isset($x) ? $x : (isset($y) ? $y : $z)
```

The null coalesce operator acts exactly like `isset()` : the subject variable's value is taken if:

- The variable is defined (it exists)
- **The variable is not null**

Just a note for PHP beginners: if you use the ternary condition but you know that the subject variable is necessarily defined (but you want a fallback for *falsy* values), there's the [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php):

```
$var = $dict['optional'] ?: 'fallback';
```

With the *Elvis operator*, if `$dict['optional']` is an invalid offset or `$dict` is undefined, you'll get a `E_NOTICE` warning (PHP 5 & 7). That's why, in PHP 5, people are using the hideous *isset a ? a : b* form when they're not sure about the input.

Answer (score 2):

If you only assign `null` instead of the non set variable, you can use:

`$a = @$the->very->long->variable[$index];`

`@` makes that instruction throw no errors

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know that `$the->very->long->variable` is set, and you're just worried about the array index....

```
$x = $the->very->long->variable;
$a = isset($x[$index]) ? $x[$index] : null;
```

Or for a more generic variant that you can use around you code:

```
function array_valifset($arr,$k, $default=null) {
    return isset($arr[$k]) ? $arr[$k] : $default;
}
```

then call it like this for any array value:

```
$a = array_valifset($the->very->long->variable,$index);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that I had merely overlooked a built-in feature. Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: nope. as @eisberg says, the PHP devs have explicitly rejected a shorthand isset solution.  :-(  I'm sure they have their reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across the same problem and discovered that referencing an array element does not issue a notice or warning but returns null (at least PHP 5.6).

```
$foo = ['bar' => 1];

var_dump($bar = &$foo['bar']); // int 1
var_dump($baz = &$foo['baz']); // null
```

Inside an if statement:

```
if($bar = &$foo['bar']) {
    echo $bar;
}
if($baz = &$foo['baz']) {
    echo $baz;
}
```