# Short version of $x ? $x : $y expression

Tags: php

My intention is to find a short version of:

```
$x ? $x : $y
```

where $x gets evaluated only once.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP can test it themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [?: operator PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-php) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: valid (assuming `$x` is defined (and same for `$y` if `$x` is falsey)), but pointless.  It's a no-op.  Are you thinking of doing something like `$x = $x?: $y;`?

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP manual entry on [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to TRUE, and `expr3` otherwise.

So, you'll need to be using PHP 5.3 or greater to get this "shortcut" feature. Although, why you'd want a shortcut for an operator that already is a shortcut is another question...

Comment: Maybe for actions like these: `$val = findById($id) ?: createWithId($id);` ? It's a stupid approach, but PHP isn't that logical imho (comparing with other languages, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **[it is valid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**.

You know, you could have just tried it. :)

http://3v4l.org/68Zrf

Comment: -1 Perhaps add some supporting documentation or explain *why* it's valid

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: You mean, like I just did..?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer!