# Shortest if/else using ternary operators

Tags: php

I have this piece of code:

```
<?=!empty($options["placeholder"]) ? $options["placeholder"]:'search...'?>
```

I was under the impression I could do like:

```
<?=!empty($options["placeholder"]) ?:'search...'?>
```

But when `$options["placeholder"]` is not empty then it returns 1, as it is a ternary operator.

Do I have to always issue the variable 2 times?

Comment: `Do I have to always issue the variable 2 times?` Yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can be sure that `$options['placeholder']` will be set--if not you can prefix it with `@` to suppress the warning--you can drop the `empty` call:

```
<?= $options["placeholder"] ?: 'search...' ?>
```

The [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-php) `?:` evaluates to the left hand side if it is *truthy* (`true` when coerced to a `boolean` value such as `1` or a non-empty string `'foo'`) or the right hand side if not.

Comment: I finally understood the **Elvis** operator. `?:`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is however been many requests wanting to change this:

- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor
- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset-set-operator