# Ternary statement without middle expression

Tags: php, ternary

How to replace this :

```
if( $this->getInfo() ){
   $value = $this->getInfo();
}else{
   $value = $this->getAnotherInfo();
}
```

This would be nicer solution :

```
$value = $this->getInfo() ? $this->getInfo() : $this->getAnotherInfo();
```

But we repeat `$this->getInfo()`.

Comment: first, assign the result of `$this->getInfo()` to the variable, then work with this variable. Otherwise you can't escape double calling of this method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [?: operator PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-php)

Comment: But in this expr `$var = fn() ? : 1;` fn() called once. Tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fun:

```
$value = $this->getInfo() ? : $this->getAnotherInfo();
```

Comment: Did you correctly answer your own question? Looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: @Popnoodles: No, that's valid syntax. It's called the shorthand ternary syntax. See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary): "*Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.*".

Comment: Ok thanks, I've never seen it before. So he answered his own question.

Answer (score 0):

If it bothers you having to repeat the expression you could write a function that returns the first truthy value.

```
$value = which ($this->getInfo(), $this->getAnotherInfo());

function which () { 
    if (func_num_args()<1) return false;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $s) if ($s) return $s;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A *nasty* option would be this:

```
if (!($value = $this->getInfo())) $value = $this->getOtherInfo();
```

If the assignment returns `false` assign the other value.

But aside from this looking disgusting, it is still repetitive, albeit in a different way.

---

[As of PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), you can leave out the middle part of the ternary operator and avoid the repetition:

```
$value = $this->getInfo() ? : $this->getOtherInfo();
```

Which does what you want.