# JavaScript "or"-functionality in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following Code in PHP

```
if($row["phone"])
  $phone = $row["phone"];
else
  $phone = $row["mobile"];
```

In JavaScript I could simply write

```
phone = row.phone || row.mobile;
```

which is much easier to write, and looks much better. If I try the same in PHP it would simply return `true`

```
$phone = $row["phone"] || $row["mobile"];
echo $phone;     // 1
```

Is there any operator in PHP that offers me the same functionality as the in JavaScript?
I tried the bitwise or `|`, but that only works sometimes and sometimes i get really weird results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/3661794).
You can use the elvis operator like this:

```
$phone = $row['phone'] ?: $row['mobile'];
```

This would be shorter than

```
$phone = $row['phone'] ? $row['phone'] : $row['mobile'];
```

Comment: Ok now this is EXACTLY, what i was looking for. Short and sweet

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the logical operators always return a boolean value, so you have to do the job as you've done in your question. You can also write using a ternary operator:

```
$phone = $row['phone'] ? $row['phone'] : $row['mobile'];
```

Comment: this `?` seems to be the one im looking for. can you give a short explanation on how exactly this works?

Comment: @chillichief that's ternary operator. google about it.

Comment: ok i got it. it is literally just a shorhand version of the code i wrote. THX

Comment: It is basically shorthand for if--else. @chillichief