# Elvis operator etymology

Tags: operator-keyword, naming

According to Wikipedia, the binary operator `?:` is

> colloquially referred to as the **Elvis operator** due to its **resemblance to an emoticon**.

My question is:

- Does the name have anything to do with Elvis Presley?
- How exactly does it resemble *Elvis*?

Comment: Read the links in Wikipedia article, the first one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php

Comment: @CiaPan Just deleted my answer, because that [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/15393) has an awesome image, that explains it perfectly!

Comment: Thank you guys! If someone wants to get an accepted answer, please add it below :)

Answer (score 30):

Yes, it relates to Elvis Presley because it kinda resembles his hair style:

[image: Elvis emoticon]

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/432311