# Is there a shorter syntax for the ternary operator in php?

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements

How can I create a shorter expression of:

```
$variable = @$array["property"] ? $array["property"] : DEFAULT_VALUE_CONSTANT;
```

To something like this:

```
$variable = @$array["property"] || DEFAULT_VALUE_CONSTANT;
```

Now I get `true` / `false`

Comment: Shorter? Why would you want shorter?

Comment: @JayBlanchard because the property tested to be set is the one that is returned. It seems like a surplus to me.

Comment: Null coalescing? PHP 7 => http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php `$a ?? $b ?? $c`

Comment: Yes its there but as @Fred-ii- your PHP version need to be `>=7`. Once more question why you were suppressing error instead you can use `isset` function

Comment: Apparently, it is now possible in PHP7 using Null Coalescing operator.

Comment: @Uchiha i am just lazy :)

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y yes I figured it out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's possible in PHP7 with [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (`??`)

```
$variable = $array["property"] ?? DEFAULT_VALUE_CONSTANT;
```

If you are using PHP version < 7 one solution is use the [elvis operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#)

```
$variable = $array["property"] ?: DEFAULT_VALUE_CONSTANT;
```

Please avoid using `@` instead of `isset()`.

**References:**

[?: operator (the 'Elvis operator') in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993409/1342547)

Comment: Yes @fred-ii- commented about it. But my hosting provider supports 5.6.7 for now. I guess there is not much I can do.

Comment: @KristosAthanasiadis how about the elvis operator? `$array["property"] ?: DEFAULT_VALUE_CONSTANT;`

Comment: you are absolutely right. That's the operator I was looking for! Can you edit your answer?

Comment: thank you! it works as expected and yes there is no need for the error suppression

Comment: The suppression @ is needed finally (so ignore partially the previous comment) otherwise I need to use the full ternary operator, cause if I use isset(), I will get a true | false result and not the variable tested to be set

Comment: @KristosAthanasiadis no problem, sometimes people use `@` and does not why, if you have a reason it's ok :)

Comment: When you cannot change the error reporting (like me) in your environment, the @ is sometimes necessary. Anyway thank you :)