# PHP - convert string empty to null

Tags: php, string, null

I have a php page when get the values from $_GET variables and put this in a php query with two condition:

```
AND book_id = '$bookid"
AND book_date between coalesce('$bookdate',book_date) AND coalesce('$bookdate',book_date)
```

The problem is this condition: `AND book_date between coalesce('$bookdate',book_date) AND coalesce('$bookdate',book_date)`
To work, the query want '$bookdate' = null, and when retrieve the variables, set the value as a string.

How to make this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If this is really part of a database query, be warned that it is widely open for SQL injection. To avoid getting hacked, use prepared statements

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator):

```php
$bookdate = $_GET['bookdate'] ?: null;
```

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/12750122

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will just to need to conditionally declare your variable before use in the query.

```
$bookdate = !strlen($bookdate) ? null : $bookdate
```

Or perhaps more appropriately from `$_GET`...

```
$bookdate = empty($_GET['bookdate']) ? null : $bookdate
```

...because your variable name insinuates a date-type value, I will assume that a `0` value will not be passed or would not be valid for your use case.  I say this because `empty()` evaluates `0` as `true`.

*Superglobal elements should be checked for *existence* before you try to access/manipulate them to avoid receiving Notices.  (e.g. `isset()` or `empty()` or `array_key_exists()`)

Ultimately, you should not be directly injecting variables into your query.  You should be using a prepared statement and binding your variables to placeholders.

Answer (score -1):

check the variable before you make your sql query:

`$bookdate = !empty($bookdate) ? $bookdate : null;`