# Ternary Operator(Elvis Operator) ?:

Tags: php

I'm just wondering why this code returns 1

```
$complete = 'complete';
$completed = ($complete == 'complete') ?: 'Not Complete';
```

while if I try this one

```
$complete = 'complete';
$completed = ($complete == 'complete') ? $complete : 'Not Complete';
```

and this one

```
$complete = 'complete';
if ($complete == 'complete') {
    $completed = $complete;
} else {
    $completed = 'Not Complete';
}
```

they both returns `'complete'`

base on this [?: operator (the 'Elvis operator') in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top)

aren't they all supposed to return the same value?

Comment: in the first example it returns the expression `($complete == 'complete')` which resolves to true/1. The others return `$complete`. (I suppose that's a typo in the second example: `..? $completeD :..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you make a boolean check in the first example:

`$complete == 'complete' // returns 'true'`

And the operator tells, *if the statement is true, return the value of the statement, otherwise return 'not Complete'*. So it does. And `true` is represented as `1`.

Explained by your examples:

```
// sets '$completed' to '($complete == 'complete')' what is 'true'
$completed = ($complete == 'complete') ?: 'Not Complete';

// sets '$completed' to '$completed', what is 'NULL', because '$completed' seems to be undefined before
$completed = ($complete == 'complete') ? $completed : 'Not Complete';

// sets '$completed' to the value of '$complete', because the statement is 'true'
if ($complete == 'complete') {
    $completed = $complete;
} else {
    $completed = 'Not Complete';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elvis Operator this way:

```
$completed = $complete ?: 'Not Complete';
```

In your code you have a statement like this case:

```
$completed = true ?: 'Not Complete';
```

therefore it returns true.