# How do I fix this "Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter" error message with WordPress categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have the below function in functions.php of the WordPress theme I'm working with. It's supposed to exclude a designated post category (such as "Uncategorized") from being displayed on the front-end of a website. It does work for that purpose.

```
function the_category_filter($thelist,$separator=' ') {
     // list the IDs of the categories to exclude
     $exclude = array(1);
     // create an empty array
     $exclude2 = array();

     // loop through the excluded IDs and get their actual names
     foreach($exclude as $c) {
          // store the names in the second array
          $exclude2[] = get_cat_name($c);
     }

     // get the list of categories for the current post     
     $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
     // create another empty array      
     $newlist = array();

     foreach($cats as $cat) {
          // remove the tags from each category
          $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));

          // check against the excluded categories
          if(!in_array($catname,$exclude2))

          // if not in that list, add to the new array
          $newlist[] = $cat;
     }
     // return the new, shortened list
     return implode($separator,$newlist);
}

// add the filter to 'the_category' tag
add_filter('the_category','the_category_filter', 10, 2);
```

However, in certain custom post types with different categories than the one that I'm selecting for in the above code, when I'm creating a new post, I get this error

> Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter

in the Categories selection panel on the right-hand side of the post editor.

[image]

This line is the one it's saying is incorrect:

`$cats = explode($separator,$thelist);`

I've tried wrapping that part of the code in an `if` condition to check for the empty delimiter, like this:

```
 if ( !empty( explode($separator,$thelist) ) ) {     
     $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
     // create another empty array      
     $newlist = array();

     foreach($cats as $cat) {
          // remove the tags from each category
          $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));

          // check against the excluded categories
          if(!in_array($catname,$exclude2))

          // if not in that list, add to the new array
          $newlist[] = $cat;
     }
     // return the new, shortened list
     return implode($separator,$newlist);
 }
```

But while that does make the error disappear from the Categories panel, what results is a bunch of blanks where the category names ought to appear.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your !empty needs to check only the $separator, not the full expression

Comment: Thanks. I had tried it that way before, but the categories still were blank. Trying it again now at your suggestion, I realized I also needed an `else` condition at the end to do `return $thelist;` so that the list would output instead of being all blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the answers given by Martin and aynber, I solved the problem with this code:

```
function the_category_filter($thelist,$separator=' ') {
     // list the IDs of the categories to exclude
     $exclude = array(1);
     // create an empty array
     $exclude2 = array();

     // loop through the excluded IDs and get their actual names
     foreach($exclude as $c) {
          // store the names in the second array
          $exclude2[] = get_cat_name($c);
     }

     // get the list of categories for the current post   
    if ( !empty( $separator ) && !empty( $thelist ) ) {       
         $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
         // create another empty array      
         $newlist = array();

         foreach($cats as $cat) {
              // remove the tags from each category
              $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));

              // check against the excluded categories
              if(!in_array($catname,$exclude2))

              // if not in that list, add to the new array
              $newlist[] = $cat;
         }
         // return the new, shortened list
         return implode($separator,$newlist);
    } else {
        return $thelist;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great you resolved it! Please see my update and warning about using `strip_tags` function.

Comment: I removed that line and the function still works as intended. I'll look into the `preg_replace()` function as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
> ```

The source value `$separator`is not allowed to be an empty string (or equivilant), therefore you can either check the value before you run the `explode` or you can use [**a ternary operator**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854998/ternary-operatorelvis-operator) within the function:

## A

Ensure the given `$seperator` value is not empty;

```
if ( !empty($separator) && !empty($thelist) ) {     
    $cats = explode($separator, $thelist);
 }
```

Example using **A** here:

```
$seperator = "";
$thelist = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";

$cats = "failed";
if ( !empty($separator) && !empty($thelist) ) {     
    $cats = explode($separator, $thelist);
 }

 print_r($cats);
 // output string "failed"
```

## B

Set a default seperator value of your choice if it is empty;

```
if (!empty($thelist) ) {     
    $cats = explode( ($separator?:' '),$thelist);
 }
```

Example using **B** here:

```
$seperator = "";
$thelist = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";

$cats = "failed";
if (!empty($thelist) ) {     
    $cats = explode(($separator?:' '),$thelist);
 }

 print_r($cats);
 // output array of numerical values.
```

---

Further to your question:

> ```
> $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));
> ```

The "Strip_tags" function is extremely problematic and can easily return empty strings if the HTML tags in the string do not line up, such as `<p>something here.` this can result in empty strings as you example. I can't say if this is what's happening for you but I would suggest you try and comment out this function and see if that improves the result.

I would suggest you can build yourself a more robust [**`preg_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) functionality to remove specific characters such as anything that is not alphanumeric, etc..