# How often will a function be called when it seems te be used twice in a PHP ternary operation?

Tags: php, performance, conditional-operator

When I use a ternary operation in PHP like this:

```
$dataObject = $this->someInstance->getDataFromDB(); //getDataFromDB() for example returns an object or false. It gets data from a database ;-)
$variable = !$dataObject ? false : $dataVariable;
```

Then `getDataFromDB()` is called once.

But how often is it called and how often will data from a DB be fetched, when I use the ternary operation like this:

```
$variable = !$this->someInstance->getDataFromDB() ? false : $this->someInstance->getDataFromDB();
```

I would prefer the first version when it performs better.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you do it way number two it is called twice because you're not storing results and in certain cases it might be possible to get two different sets of results depending on what is returned from `getDataFromDB()` You're only testing for truthiness.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php)

Comment: If that method already returns an object or false, setting something to its result or false with a ternary seems redundant. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I was thinking the same thing and was hoping it was just an example and didn't want to write a dissertation on it :)

Comment: OP  Did you give up???

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Yes of course this is just an example-pseudo-code and not the way code should look like ;-) But this is in my opinion the best way to point on the true 'problem'. I just want to understand the mechanics and behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example `getDataFromDB()` may be called twice if the first expression evaluates to `false` or you could do it like this:

```
$variable = !($d = $this->someInstance->getDataFromDB()) ? false : $d;
```

Or possibly:

```
$variable = $this->someInstance->getDataFromDB() ?: false;
```

I'm assuming that the two `:` was a typo.