# PHP Operators ?? vs ?:

Tags: php, operators

I recently read some PHP code and I've seen two operators :

- `A ?? B` operator which seems to mean take A if A is not null else take B
- `A ?: B` operator this one is the a shortcut for the ternary operator but the effect is the same it take A if A is not null and B otherwise.

Is there any difference between them ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php
you can take a look at this question to find out!