# PHP echo $foo ? 'bar' without the false part?

Tags: php

Is there any way to write this

`echo $foo ? 'bar' : '';`

but without the false part? Just like this:

`echo $foo ? 'bar';`

and nothing would be echoed if `$foo` is false automatically?

I often find that I just want to echo something if it's true but don't care about an else statement :)

Comment: [elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php) perhaps... `?:`

Comment: I would think a simple and boring `if ($foo) echo 'bar';` would do?

Comment: Yeah but sometimes I want to do it in an echo and not a separate if statement. ?: only returned true for me not the variable.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius ah, that one just returns the left side if it’s true, otherwise the right, which is useful at times too. I want to return the right side only if left is true.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work with `echo`, but using `print()` your can do:

```php
$foo && print('bar');
```

---

I just discovered that parentheses aren't even needed for `print`, so a bit shorter would be:

```php
$foo && print 'bar';
```

---

Please also note @IMSoP's striking comment below, about parentheses for `echo` and `print`:

> Note also that neither echo nor print is a function, and using parentheses like you have here is a habit to avoid, as it can sometimes be misleading - e.g. print('hello') && true; will output "1", not "hello" - the parentheses mean nothing, and the value passed to print is the result of 'hello' && true

Comment: Thanks! I need it to work in echo. Or laravel/blade style class=”{{ $foo ? ’bg-gray’ : ’’ }} without the last part :) I guess I’d use the same with js/alpine.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases when [the alternative "and" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator) is useful: because it has low precedence, you can write things like `$foo = someFunc() and print 'bar';` rather than needing parentheses for `($foo = someFunc()) && print 'bar';`

Comment: @SeaBass You mix template engine syntax with PHP syntax.
So you asked the wrong question.

Comment: Note also that neither `echo` nor `print` is a function, and using parentheses like you have here is a habit to avoid, as it can sometimes be misleading - e.g. `print('hello') && true;` will output "1", not "hello" - the parentheses mean nothing, and the value passed to `print` is the result of `'hello' && true`

Comment: @cottton no I don’t mix it. I’d use it in plain php too.

Comment: @IMSoP I've incorporated your remark about parentheses into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own function to do this:

```
function when($returnContent,$content)
{
  return $returnContent ? $content : '';
}
```

That is simple enough, you can use it like this:

```
echo 'text before ' . when($foo, 'middle text ') . ' text at end.';
```

Perhaps not what you had in mind, but it does the job.

Comment: Yes, so I guess no built-in way for this in PHP. Thank you! Good suggestion/workaround.